# Locus of points in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry, locus

I have a problem where I need to find a locus of all points in the complex plane that satisfy $|z-ia|=\lambda|z+ia|$, where $z=x+iy$, and $\lambda>0$.

I know I need to get a circle with the radius $ \left| \dfrac{2\lambda a}{1-\lambda^2} \right|$, centred ant $ z = ia \left[ \dfrac{1+\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2} \right] $

I tried to express $|z\pm ia|$ in terms of real numbers using $|z \pm ia|=\sqrt{x^2 + (y \pm a)^2}$ and trying to express it in the form of a circle, that is $ (x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2 = r^2 $, but I just couldn't manage, as the algebra becomes really involved. Maybe someone could help me with the next step in this problem or suggest a different way of approaching it? Not looking for a full answer.

Comment: The algebra involved is quite simple. Do you know that $|a+b|^{2}=|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}+2 \Re (a\overline {b})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is simply the Apollonius Circle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius

---

If you want to find this explicitly, we have
$$x^2+(y-a)^2=\lambda^2x^2+\lambda^2(y+a)^2$$
$$\therefore x^2(1-\lambda^2)+y^2(1-\lambda^2)-2\lambda^2ay-2ay=\lambda^2a^2-a^2 \implies x^2+y^2-\frac{2ay(1+\lambda^2)}{1-\lambda^2}=-a^2$$
Completing the square in the LHS,
$$x^2+(y-\frac{a(1+\lambda^2)}{1-\lambda^2})^2=-a^2+(\frac{a(1+\lambda^2)}{1-\lambda^2})^2$$
After a little simplification, we get the desired result
$$x^2+(y-\frac{a(1+\lambda^2)}{1-\lambda^2})^2=(\frac{2a\lambda}{1-\lambda^2})^2$$
Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you not miss the $ -2ay+a^2 $ on the LHS in your second equation?

Comment: Ahhh yes! I'm terribly sorry. I'll fix it

Comment: This website is the most useful. Thank you so much.